# Matlab: Making errorbar() draw uninterrupted lines for NaN values in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, nan

I have a matrix M of data and a matrix E of errors that I want to plot with errorbar against an independent variable x. I would also like lines between points in the same row. One column in M or E corresponds to one x-value, so this can be accomplished with

```
errorbar(x, M, E, 'o-')
```

I am missing some data points and these have the value `NaN`. As it should `errorbar()` ignores these, but the line between the points closest two points in the same row (the one resulting from the `'-'` option) is broken.

I have seen some different solutions that work with vectors as opposed to matrices, involving  `~any(isnan(y),1)` and `L=~(isnan(x)|isnan(y))`, but these lead to problems like

```
Error using errorbar
X, Y and error bars must all be the same length
```

I can't find a solution for matrices, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the missing data points are probably not the same for every line I advice to plot in a loop like this (assuming plot data are columns of the matrices):

```
for i = 1 : size(M, 2)
  data = M(:, i);
  good = not(isnan(data));
  xi = x(good);
  data = data(good);
  error = E(good, i);
  errorbar(xi, data, error, 'o-');
  hold on;
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there's an easier way but maybe not.